# MS Graph create event 400 bad request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have code that get's the default calendar and stores the id in a variable called calendar id. I then I then get a list of availabilities (which are events in our system) the end time and the start time are recorded in utc and I want to put those events into an office 365 calendar.

This is my code which is generating and 400 Bad request. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", msBearerToken);
    var callJson = new
    {
        Subject = "Booking",
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = BodyType.Html,
            Content = "Available"
        },
        Start = new DateTimeTimeZone
        {
            DateTime = availabilitySummery.StartDateUTC.ToString(),
            TimeZone = "Europe/London"
        },
        End = new DateTimeTimeZone
        {
            DateTime = availabilitySummery.EndDateUTC.ToString(),
            TimeZone = "Europe/London"
        }
    };
    string path = $"/me/calendars/{calendarId}/events";
   // string path = "/me/calendars/events";
    path = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0" + path;
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(path, callJson);}
```

Comment: can you check the actual response body ? It may contains details about the error. That said, how do you retrieve your token ? Did you follow all steps to register an AAD application, declare permissions and consented them?

Comment: Also, datetime.tostring will be produce a human readable sttring, not a ISO 8601 date string. Can you try .ToString("o") ?

Answer (score 0):

Date should be ISO8601 formatted.

Replace `.ToString()` by `.ToString("o")` when you want to convert dates to string.

Ref: [The round-trip ("O", "o") format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier)

And [createdDateTime property of event object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

Answer (score 0):

Update: This worked:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())     
{

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", msBearerToken);
    var callJson = new
    {
        Subject = "Booking",
        Body = new
        {
            ContentType = BodyType.Html.ToString(),
            Content = "Available"
        },
        Start = new 
        {
            DateTime = availabilitySummery.StartDateUTC.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"),
            TimeZone = "GMT Standard Time"
        },
        End = new 
        {
            DateTime = availabilitySummery.EndDateUTC.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"),
            TimeZone = "GMT Standard Time"
        }
    };
    string path = $"/me/calendars/{calendarId}/events";
    string jsoncall = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(callJson);
    path = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0" + path;
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(path, callJson);
    string content = await  responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (!responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return false;
    }        
}
```